# How can I list all virtual networks for a given network interface in linux?

Tags: ifconfig

How do I list all virtual networks created for a given network interface card?

E.g. I have added a virtual network like this,

```
ifconfig eth0:0 inet6 add ::123/64
```

It's responding fine. And I know I can use that network, because I added it. But if I wasn't the one who added it, how would I find out that it existed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the ip command, specifically:

```
ip addr show dev eth0
```

This should give you all ip addresses that are assigned to `eth0`.  Or leave off the `dev eth0` arguments to get the same for all interfaces on the system.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a Linux expert but I thought that was deprecated and replaced with `iproute2` commands?  See [`iproute2` documentation](http://www.noah.org/wiki/iproute2#labeling_virtual_interfaces_for_compatibility_with_.60ifconfig.60).

But I think you can still get what you have setup with either `ifconfig -a` or `netstat -ian`.

You should wait till the real Linux admins chime in though or you can try what I posted.